# How to define a propety that can be of an email format or an empty string in openapi specification (swagger)

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an email field which users send as part of POST/PUT API. I want to validate using openapi specification that the email is in correct email format if it's present. If it is given as an empty string, I don't want to do the check. How can I achieve this.

I know how to accept null values

```
email:
    type: string
    format: email
    nullable: true
```

But I want to accept empty string, not null. Is there something we can do for this like below

```
email:
  type: string
  anyOf:
    format: email
    format: empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `format` is not used for validation purposes. This is what is called an `annotation` in the JSON Schema world, which OpenAPI is based upon. It's merely an informational property. Some validators or tooling will use this property to enhance a validation result but it's not required to do so.

In your case, any string value is technically valid from a JSON Schema validation point of view, including empty string.

```yaml
email:
  type: string
  format: email
  nullable: false
```